# How to Modify embedded struct in golang?

Tags: go, pointers, struct, reflection, interface

i want to set the fields of my embedded struct in golang,
how can i achieve this.
Tried using reflection but not working for me.

```
type ProductTypeDbModel struct {
    Entity.BaseEntity
    Id            int64  `json:"id" db:"id"`
    Name          string `json:"name" db:"name"`
    DisplayName   string `json:"display_name" db:"display_name"`
    ShortCode     string `json:"short_code" db:"short_code"`
    Version       int64  `json:"version" db:"version"`
    IsDeleted     int64  `json:"is_deleted" db:"is_deleted"`
    NamespaceCode string `json:"namespace_code" db:"namespace_code"`
}

type BaseEntity struct {
    Id        int64     `db:"id"`
    CreatedBy int64     `db:"created_by"`
    UpdatedBy int64     `db:"updated_by"`
    CreatedAt time.Time `db:"created_at"`
    UpdatedAt time.Time `db:"updated_at"`
    Version   int64     `db:"version"`
}
```

My ProductTypeDb model is struct implements BaseRepository.

Now i have Base Repo object of type ProductTypeDbModel, and i want to modify/ set the updated by value in this.

Tried the below code .

```
func SetUpdatedByToBaseRepository(model BaseRepository, updatedByValue int64) (BaseRepository, error) {
    val := reflect.ValueOf(model)

    for i := 0; i < val.NumField(); i++ {
        field := val.Type().Field(i)
        fieldName := field.Name

        if field.Anonymous {
            // Get the value of the embedded struct field
            embeddedField := val.Field(i)

            // Check if the embedded field is valid and addressable
            if embeddedField.Kind() == reflect.Struct && embeddedField.CanSet() {
                // Set the value of the UpdatedBy field in the embedded struct
                if fieldName == "BaseEntity" {
                    // Get the field value of UpdatedBy within BaseEntity
                    updatedByField := embeddedField.FieldByName("UpdatedBy")
                    if updatedByField.IsValid() && updatedByField.CanSet() {
                        updatedByField.SetInt(updatedByValue)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return model, nil
}
```

But embeddedField.CanSet() is returning false, how can i make this happen.

Comment: I'm assuming `BaseRepository` is an interface. If so, I believe you have to call `.Elem()` on `val` to dig up the concrete value stored in the interface value. I am a bit rusty on the internal workings of interface values, but I think this might not be possible unless `model` was assigned a `*ProductTypeDbModel` rather than a `ProductTypeDbModel`.

Answer (score 0):

```
func SetUpdatedByToBaseRepository(model interface{}, updatedByValue int64) error {
val := reflect.ValueOf(model)
if val.Kind() != reflect.Ptr || val.Elem().Kind() != reflect.Struct {
    return errors.New("model must be a pointer to a struct")
}
val = val.Elem() 

baseEntityField := val.FieldByName("BaseEntity")
if baseEntityField.IsValid() {
    updatedByField := baseEntityField.FieldByName("UpdatedBy")
    if updatedByField.IsValid() && updatedByField.CanSet() {
        updatedByField.SetInt(updatedByValue)
        return nil
    }
}
return errors.New("unable to set UpdatedBy")
```

}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).